# Set up twitter stream to get live streams from a user based on keywords

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

If I want a stream when Trump tweets anything with the word "racist" or "immigration", how do I do that? I am not sure even this works, let alone how to add multiple keywords to the query.

```
public static void Stream_SampleStreamExample()
{
    var stream = Stream.CreateUserStream();
    stream.AddCustomQueryParameter("realDonaldTrump", "racist");
    stream.MessageReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Message.Text);
    };

    stream.AddTweetLanguageFilter(LanguageFilter.English);            

    stream.StartStream();
}
```

Do I have to follow a user first?

```
public static void AuthenticatedUser_FollowUser(string userName)
{
    var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
    var userToFollow = User.GetUserFromScreenName(userName);

    if (authenticatedUser.FollowUser(userToFollow))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have successfully sent a request to follow {0}", userToFollow.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now this works. First

```
string userStr = "realDonaldTrump";

// From a user screen name
user = User.GetUserFromScreenName(userStr);
userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(user.Id);
```

Add the keywords to match on:

```
fs.AddTrack("immigration");
...
```

Setup a filtered stream:

```
IFilteredStream fs = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
and so on...
```

Then, inside OnMatchedTweet, see if the creator of the tweet is the user you want.

```
OnMatchedTweet(object sender, MatchedTweetReceivedEventArgs args)
{        
    if (args.Tweet.CreatedBy.Id != user.Id)
        return;
    ...
}
```